# Spring Session Spring Security Rest API and Redis

Tags: spring, spring-session

I am new to using Spring Session and Spring Security. Hope can get help. I want to use Spring Session and Spring Security on REST API and using Redis to store the session information. I followed the sample from http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/rest.html But I use xml instead of Java class and I am using Spring 3.2.4.

There is no problem when I use curl with username:password, x-auth-token is saved in Redis and 200 ok is obtained in the header. 
However, problem is encountered when I use curl WITHOUT username and password. 401 unauthorized is obtained but there is x-auth-token returned in the header and it is also saved in Redis


    `< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
    * Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
    < Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    < x-auth-token: 71554566-17d3-44ca-94b8-009d090c61a1
    < Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
    < Content-Language: en
    < Content-Length: 1018
    < Date: Mon, 21 Mar 2016 14:40:18 GMT`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is due to the fact that the previous request is being saved. You can fix this using [NullRequestCache](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/samples/rest/src/main/java/sample/SecurityConfig.java#L37). In XML you can leverage [`<request-cache>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-request-cache). The configuration looks something like:

```
<http ...>

    <request-cache ref="requestCache"/>
</http>

<b:bean id="requestCache" class="org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.NullRequestCache"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. This issue haunted me for several days already.